# Edit json file with python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have big json file, about 500mb, like next:

```
[
    {"title": "title1 here", "text": ["text1 here"]},
    {"title": "title2 here", "text": ["text2 here"]},
    {...
]
```

I'd like to make changes in titles and text. How can I do it? I decided to read titles and texts as strings and after save it to json format again. It's ok with reading and making changes:

```
f = open('test.json')
data = json.load(f)

for i in range(len(data)):
    #print(data[i]['title'])
    changedTitle = data[i]['title'].split()
    changedText = data[i]['text']
    shuffle(changedTitle)
    shuffle(changedText)
    changedTitle = " ".join(changedTitle)
    changedText = " ".join(changedText) 
    print(changedTitle)
    print(changedText)
```

So I got changedTitle and changedText in loop and have no idea how to construct json file from it. Please advice. Thanks.

I decided to read titles and texts as strings and after save it to json format again.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**:

Reassign the changed title and text back into the data at the same index you read it from. For example:

```
for i in range(len(data)):
    #print(data[i]['title'])

    # Read from data at specific index
    changedTitle = data[i]['title'].split()
    changedText = data[i]['text']

    # Change data values
    changedTitle = shuffle(changedTitle)
    changedText = shuffle(changedText)

    # Reassign changed values back to original indices
    data[i]['title'] = " ".join(changedTitle)
    data[i]['text'] = " ".join(changedText)
```

and then to save back to a json file

```
with open('your_file_name.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(data, f)
```

Comment: Yes, that's what you do, but you forgot to save it back to the file.

Comment: Anything else you need?

Comment: No, that's fine now.